# It is possible to run Xdebug only in a test subdomain which is in the same hosting that the production one?

Tags: php, testing, xdebug, production

I've two WordPress installations, one in test.mydomain.com and another in mydomain.com (production).
Both are in the same hosting.

To avoid the slowdown in the production site, would it be possible to limit Xdebug extension to debug the test site sparing the other?

One more thing: my provider **doesn't allow containers with Docker**.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on how the servers are set up. If you can have different PHP-FPM pools for your test and production subdomain, then you can configure one to have Xdebug, and the other one without.

It is not possible to have PHP running once (one PHP-FPM pool, one Apache environment) and Xdebug not loaded or enabled for only some sub domains, as it needs to load when PHP itself loads.